# Foreign key is inserted null with CascadeType.PERSIST,- Spring Data Jpa

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables Parent and Child. They have one to one relation between them. When I save the Parent table it should insert into the Child table as well. A child table is inserted but the foreign key is null in the child table. I want a foreign key to be the autogenerated value from the Parent table.

I am using the Postgres database.

Here are my entity relations:

```
@Table(name = "`PARENT`")
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
public class Parent{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "`RPT_PARM_ID`")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    //Other column mappings.

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private Child child;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "`CHILD`")
@Setter
@Getter
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "`ID`")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    //Other column mappings
    @OneToOne(optional = false,cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @JoinColumn(name = "`PARAM_ID`", referencedColumnName ="`RPT_PARM_ID`"  )
    private Parent parent;
}

//This is how I save the code
pubilc void save(){
  Parent parent = new Parent();
  //set other fields for parent.
  Child child =new Child();
  //set other fields in child.
  parent.setChild(child);
  repository.save(parent);
}
```

In child table, PARAM_ID is inserted null, but I want the column value from RPT_PARM_ID (this is auto-generated)

Comment: Make sure you make both side sync when saving in bidirectional relation.

Comment: I don't have an issue with selecting, when I select Parent it retrieves Child, So sync is fine I believe.

Comment: No I say when save set parent in child and child in parent then foriegn key will be updated

Comment: Yes, I used @PrePersist and calling child.setParent(this); in the parent, Still no luck.